# android: How to move object base on percentage of viewpager swipe?

Tags: animation

I want to move one view from center to the top right of screen. I want to move it by detecting viewpager swipe percentage. That view will reach the top right when view pager change to other page completely.

Answer (score 2):

There are three steps to this problem.

Step 1: Implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,

Step 2: There is a call back onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels), You get all the information you need to handle a translation of any other kind of effect, You can convert these values into a percentage depending on your situation.

Step 3: Every View class has a setTranslationX or setTranslationY which can be converted into terms of height of that view. Since you have the percentage value that should be easy. All the best

I have done this before.